# Keycloak only allow specific scopes

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I'm currently working on a project with keycloak using OIDC and i was wondering if it is possible to only allow specific scopes when generating tokens based on the users request.
I have a client (API) that will allow access to specific endpoints only if the access token has specific scopes defined. For requesting tokens i have another client (UI).

For example, if the user requests the scopes "openid myapp:admin" from keycloak to gain admin permissions on the api endpoints but he is a non-admin in keycloak in the UI client, the myapp:admin scope should be removed from the access token.
However, if another user with admin requests these scopes, the token should contain those.

Can someone help me because i can't get it to work, i tried adding policies and permissions to the authorization scopes but then i can't request the client scopes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I would aim to design this around claims included in the access token rather than scopes. Whenever you want dynamic behaviour in tokens the answer is usually to use claims:

- Scopes represent a static area of data, and allowed operations on that data. An example might be 'orders_read'. This is the same for all users.
- Claims tend to be used for the actual authorization. In your case a claim of 'is_admin' seems appropriate. It can be used to reduce access when required.

At Curity we have a couple of good articles on these topics that may help to clarify this for you:

- [Scope Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/)
- [Claims Best Practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look further into how to use claims with the current system we use.